# Converting Values to Columns in Spark Dataset (Convert Key & Value pair of columns to regular columns)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataframe (Java) that has the following simple schema . Here is an example instance:

```
+-------------------+
| id | key | Value  |
+-------------------+
| 01 | A   | John   |
| 01 | B   | Nick   |
| 02 | A   | Mary   |
| 02 | B   | Kathy  |
| 02 | C   | Sabrina|
| 03 | B   | George |
+-------------------+
```

I would like to transform it to the following:

```
+------------------------------+
| id | A    | B      | C       |
+------------------------------+
| 01 | John | Nick   | null    |
| 02 | Mary | Kathy  | Sabrina |
| 03 | null | George | null    |
+------------------------------+
```

I tried the pivot operator (because this is what it is actually) but worked partially because once the values A B and C become columns, the contents of the columns can only be numeric.

```
Dataset<Row> pivotTest2 = pivotTest.groupBy(col("id")).pivot("key").count();
```

What I would actually like, is in the place of the count, to put the value of the column Value, i.e., something of the form `.select(col("Value"))`, or even `.max("Value")` would work fine, but I cannot since `Value` is not an arithmetic column.

Comment: You need `first` instead of `max` or `count`

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following should work for you

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Dataset<Row> pivotTest2 = pivotTest.groupBy(col("id")).pivot("key").agg(first("Value"));
pivotTest2.show(false);
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+------+-------+
|id |A   |B     |C      |
+---+----+------+-------+
|01 |John|Nick  |null   |
|03 |null|George|null   |
|02 |Mary|Kathy |Sabrina|
+---+----+------+-------+
```